# akka cluster give false alarm in reporting node unreachable

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I got a cluster event listener running on each node who send email to notify me when nodes are unreachable, and I noticed two strange things:

1. most of the time, unreachable event are followed by reachable again event
2. when unreachable event occurs, I query the state of cluster, it shows that all node are still `UP`

Here is my conf:

```
akka {

  loglevel = INFO

  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]

  jvm-exit-on-fatal-error = on

  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    //will be overwrite on runtime
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 9989
    }
  }

  cluster {
    failure-detector {
      threshold = 12.0
      acceptable-heartbeat-pause = 10 s

    }

    use-dispatcher = cluster-dispatcher

  }

}

//relieve unreachable report rate
cluster-dispatcher {
  type = "Dispatcher"
  executor = "fork-join-executor"
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 4
    parallelism-max = 8
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the cluster membership lifecycle section in the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/common/cluster.html#Membership_Lifecycle

Unreachability is temporary, and indicates that there were no heartbeats for a while from the remote node. This can be reverted once heartbeats come again. This is useful to reroute data from overloaded nodes to others or compensating smaller, intermittent networking issues. Please note that a cluster member does not go to DOWN from unreachable automatically unless configured so: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/cluster-usage.html#Automatic_vs__Manual_Downing

The reason why DOWNing is manual and not automatic by default is because of the risk of split-brain scenarios and their consequences for example when Cluster Singletons are used (which won't be singletons after the cluster falls into two parts because of a broken network cable). For more options for automatically resolving such cases there is the SBR (Split Brain Resolver) in the commercial version of Akka: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/rp-15v09p01/scala/split-brain-resolver.html

Also, DOWN-ing is permanent, a node, once marked as DOWN is forever banished from the surviving part of the cluster, i.e. even if it turns out to be alive in the future, it won't be allowed back again (see Fencing and STONITH for explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STONITH or http://advogato.org/person/lmb/diary/105.html).